# My Shell script executes again and again when it is double clicked and executed

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar

I have a shell script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar jarFileName.jar
```

when i run the jar file in the terminal using :

```
java -jar jarFileName.jar
```

it executes fine. And when i execute the shell script with:

```
./jarFileName.sh
```

It executes fine.

But when i double click the shell script the jar file keeps getting executed again and again.
Can you please help me out!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you get to know that jar file is repeatedly get executed?

Comment: it is ./jarFileName.sh

Comment: my jar file generates a report. Once the jar file completes i have appropriate messages printing in the terminal. That's how i got to know that my jar file is executed repeatedly.

Comment: It is ./shellScriptName.sh

Comment: Can you post some screenshot from Terminal, which executes it over and over?